# Margins and padding are acting weird with this HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5Dqw/

When I try to put `margin-top: 5px;` or `padding-top: 5px;` to `#newsPaneText`, it either moves the entire `#newsPane` div itself down, which I didn't even think was possible, or it moves the text inside down like 25 pixels extra, seemingly for no reason at all. On line 102, add `padding-top: 5px;` or `margin-top: 5px` to see what I'm talking about. What is going on here? I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You are probably seeing an effect due to collapsing margins.

Comment: prepare working sample in http://jsfiddle.net. It's hard to understand your issue.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dYqDX/ Experiencing additional issues not related to this problem as well though.

Comment: I guess the problem is due to `float` property, try to clear flow after using.

Comment: I editing the question to just show the `#news` on the page. The `float: left;` was incorrect and I forgot to remove it, but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was going on, but putting `display: inline-block;` in `#newsPane` and `margin-top: -10px;` in `#newsPaneText` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know my solution may be not valid but it may help you to solve your problem.

You need to add margin-top to make it work.

```
margin-top: 16px;
padding-top: 5px;
```

See [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogeshlt/p5Dqw/1/)

Comment: You didn't write a negative margin-top, you wrote 16... Is that a typo?

Comment: Ooops sorry it's a typo :(

Comment: Answer Edited due to typo.

Comment: Ummm, when I put this into `#newsPaneText`, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/ikOtbMX.png - The margin is too much, I just want 5 pixels. I don't know if this is normal, but this is what I'm seeing.

Comment: Weird in Firefox it's not work in my system but in Chrome it work strange.

Answer (score 0):

> As i understood you have to add line-height, correct me if you are
>   asking different question?
>
> in line **105** add this two lines of css (change the values if you
>   need)
>
> - `line-height:`10px;
> - `padding-top:5px`; or `margin-top 5px`;
>
> Hope this helps you